# Performance issue on MDX query when moving dimension from row to column

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot-table, mdx, ssas-tabular

I have a Tabular cube () on SSAS and I create a Pivot in Excel connection to that.

I have 2 measures and 2 dimensions. If I move one of the dimensions to column, it will take a minute or two to process.

The MDX query is different in those cases

[image: Fast - Pivot]

```
--Fast Qry & result set all on rows

SELECT {[Measures].[Sum of FairValue],[Measures].[Sum of TradeAmt]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize(DrilldownMember(CrossJoin({[HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[All],[HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[CloseDt].AllMembers}, 
{([HedgeValuation].[TicketNum].[All])}), [HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[CloseDt].AllMembers, [HedgeValuation].[TicketNum])) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  FROM [Model] WHERE ([SnapshotDt].[CurrentSnapshotDtFlag].&[Y]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

[image: Fast - Result in Management Studio]

[image: Slow Pivot]

```
--Slow and result is in column

SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin(Hierarchize(DrilldownMember(CrossJoin({[HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[All],[HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[CloseDt].AllMembers}, 
{([HedgeValuation].[TicketNum].[All])}), [HedgeValuation].[CloseDt].[CloseDt].AllMembers, [HedgeValuation].[TicketNum])), 
{[Measures].[Sum of FairValue],[Measures].[Sum of TradeAmt]}) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS  FROM [Model] 
WHERE ([SnapshotDt].[CurrentSnapshotDtFlag].&[Y])
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

[image: Slow - Result in Management Studio]

In my view, the second query only moves the rows to columns.

I appreciate if anyone can explain why these 2 different layouts have different performance, and is there any way I can improve performance for the second layout?

Comment: Have you tried to switch Values and TicketNum?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the short answer is, adding many columns to your pivot table, will degrade the performance.

Pivoting your query so you have more rows than columns will return faster results even when the same data is on the screen.  I've tested with PowerPivot and SSMS and the results are similar. less columns, more speed

additional info visit: http://tinylizard.com/power-pivot-performance-gotchas/ and https://powerpivotpro.com/2011/08/less-columns-more-rows-more-speed/ which do a better job explaining this than me.. :D

Comment: Thanks for this posting your thought on this old question :). I'll take a look into the provided links.